# MacOS Terminal start up slow, the window title transitions between "login", "env", "bash" then "zsh" - but /bin/zsh starts fast in isolation

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, macos

I am having slow terminal startup times, in the 2 seconds range BUT only when opening a new Terminal window/tab (both iTerm2 and Terminal).

When launching `zsh` from an existing terminal window it launches quickly.

```
~ % /usr/bin/time zsh -i -c exit
        0.01 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys

~ % /usr/bin/time /bin/zsh -i -c exit
        0.01 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys

~ % /usr/bin/time /bin/bash -i -c exit
        0.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys

~ % /usr/bin/time bash -i -c exit
        0.01 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
```

When opening a new window/tab, the tab title transitions between "login" "env" "bash" then finally "zsh".

[Video Link[image: Imgur]](https://i.imgur.com/ZRMxPwv.mp4)

I have tried setting the default shell to `/bin/zsh` using `chsh` and also tried to set the shell in the terminal profile to `/bin/zsh` just in case.

There is nothing in my

```
.zshrc
/etc/zshrc

.bash_profile
.profile
.bashrc
/etc/bashrc
```

And when setting fish shell as the default shell, new terminal windows start instantaneously.

Do Terminal/iTerm have their own startup scripts?

Am I missing a config file that launches on start up of zsh on MacOS?

EDIT:

Ok when using the `--login` flag, it's observably slow

```
~ % /usr/bin/time zsh --login -i -c exit
        2.10 real         0.40 user         0.77 sys
```

EDIT2:

Changing the shell to Command makes it appear instantly. Where are the config steps for a zsh login shell?

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Ok turns out homebrew added around 100 calls to set itself in my `~/.zprofile` file

[image]

Comment: That's hilarious

Comment: Looks like some kind of non-idempotent configuration change that homebrew decided to do.